# Opening New Tab in Blazor App Not Behaving as Expected

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I ran into an issue with my Blazor app in which I'm trying to open a page in a new tab and while it does open the page, it's adding extra characters to the URL for some reason. The directive at the top is this:

`@page "folder/mypage"`

In my app I'm opening the tab like this:

`await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", "folder/mypage", "_blank");`

But the URL displays like this:

`myapp.com/folder/folder/mypage`

I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong and would appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the page I'm loading this from is myapp.com/folder.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Blazor.  You have an extra `folder/` in your resolved address because that's how Javascript resolves relative URLs.  Just open `mypage` and you should be fine.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Thank you. I've updated the JS call from "folder/mypage" to "mypage" as you've suggested and it works correctly now. I wasn't sure if Blazor was doing something behind the scenes I wasn't aware of or what exactly was happening but this fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it and am surprised I didn't see this sooner.

Because the page already had /folder in the URL and I was trying to load the new tab with "folder/mypage", this caused it to add the second "folder" to the URL. I updated the JS Interop and page directive code to the following and it works correctly now.

At the top of the page I've updated the directive to:

`@page /mypage`

In my JS Interop call:

`await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", "mypage", "_blank");`

Comment: Mark your answer as the correct one whenever you can, so people can know that an answer was found.

Comment: SO is not allowing me to atm, and I'm assuming it's because I have low rep. I will be able to in 2 days.